# Applying for Hong Kong Visa while already in another country with visit Visa

Tags: visas, applications, hong-kong

Is it possible to apply for a Hong Kong Visa from the Hong Kong Embassy in Jakarta while I am staying in Indonesia on a visitors visa? Or do I have to go to my home country to apply for the visa directly from the Hong Kong embassy?

Answer (score 1):

Rules on the residence requirements vary between the competent authorities of a given country. That being said, most require you to apply for visas from your country of legal residence. This generally prevents visitors from applying while on vacation, UNLESS you can prove to them that it is an extraordinary circumstance.

All in all, you'll likely have to apply when you get back home.

Comment: According to https://www.immd.gov.hk/pdforms/ID(E)1004.pdf it is possible to apply by post

“Completed application forms, i.e. ID 1003A and ID 1003B, and all supporting documents should be submitted by the applicant or the local sponsor in one of the following ways:(a) By post directly or through the local sponsor in the HKSAR to:
Receipt and Despatch Unit
Hong Kong Immigration Department 2/F, Immigration Tower
7 Gloucester Road
Wan Chai, Hong Kong”

Comment: There is also an app https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/mobile/index.html. I’ve never used it so can’t state whether it will help the OP or not